# What's the purpose of writing bindings for C libraries for Rust?

Tags: rust

I was under the impression that bindings are intermediate layers you write so that you may use a library written in one language in an application written in another. It seems that Rust may [call C with zero overhead](http://blog.rust-lang.org/2015/04/24/Rust-Once-Run-Everywhere.html)

For a concrete example, Vulkan is a C API, yet people are working on bindings for Vulkan ([1](https://github.com/kainino0x/rust-vulkan-bind), [2](https://gist.github.com/bonsairobo/a21b768c49989415251d), [3](https://github.com/tomaka/vulkano)).

If C can be called directly from Rust, why would you want to create bindings? Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Calling C with zero runtime overhead does not mean being able to call any C function right away. As Rust can not import C headers automatically (unlike for example, Swift), someone has to rewrite declarations of each function in Rust by hand to make them callable from Rust.

Comment: @Shepmaster has a point here. Maybe you could change the question to something like "What is the purpose of C bindings in Rust on the example of Vulkan"...

Comment: @hamstergene or use the vk.xml to generate the function signatures.

Comment: @hamstergene Well, that was simple. I guess in this case the bindings are not an intermediate layer at all, but rather just a declaration of what is available to call.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While Rust can call C functions without overhead, the Rust compiler still needs to know about the existence of those functions. To tell the compiler you have to declare those functions in an `extern "C" { .. }` block. You can read more about the topic in the [FFI chapter of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html). For C functions that are used by many people (e.g. Vulkan), it makes sense to put all those declarations into a Rust library that others can just use, instead of writing the bindings themselves.

With the bindings mentioned above we simply expose the original C interface to the Rust programmer. But most Rust programmers rather want to use an API that is idiomatic in Rust (we call it "rusty"). That is: using high level concepts of Rust, like traits and closures, and being "safe".

The Vulkan libraries you linked:

- The [second](https://gist.github.com/bonsairobo/a21b768c49989415251d) link is just is a raw binding generated with a tool (rust-bindgen).
- The purpose of [tomaka's library](https://github.com/tomaka/vulkano) is to create a rusty API, so it isn't just a collection of function declarations. tomaka chooses to introduce very little overhead in order to create a library that most Rust programmers are more comfortable to use than the C interface. (by the way: tomaka did this [for OpenGL](https://github.com/tomaka/glium), too).
- I don't really know about the first library you linked, but I think it's something in between the two approaches above.

Comment: This answer together with hamstergene's comment cleared things up. If the reason for using raw bindings in the first place is to declare available functions without including headers, is this what results in zero overhead because we don't have to perform marshaling, unlike many other bindings (C#, for example)?

Comment: Note that a convention is developing in the Rust ecosystem: a crate simply re-exporting a C API (unchanged) should be name `xxx-sys` where `xxx` is the name of the C library. Then, multiple higher level crates can be built on top, from the minimalist ones (just enforcing memory safety) to higher-level ones.

Comment: I always call idiomatic Rust code 'rustic', not 'rusty'. I think it has more positive connotations.